# i18n.t doesn't parse right value in ReactJS

Tags: javascript, reactjs, internationalization

JSON file named `navigations.json`:

```
{
"sidenav.dashboard": "Dashboard",
"sidenav.profile": "Profile",
"sidenav.account": "Account",
}
```

Is used in JS file:

```
import i18n from '../../../i18n'

export const driverItems = [
{
  link: '#',
  icon: <Edit stroke="#ffffff" />,
  text: i18n.t('navigations:sidenav.dashboard'),
  open: false
},
{
  link: '#',
  icon: <Edit stroke="#ffffff" />,
  text: i18n.t('navigations:sidenav.profile'),
  open: false
},
{
  link: '#',
  icon: <Edit stroke="#ffffff" />,
  text: i18n.t('navigations:sidenav.account'),
  open: false
}
]
```

Then looping the array of objects in React component:

```
  import { ownerItems, driverItems } from './linksList'

  // then looping...

  const items = this.state.linksOwnerList.map((item, index) => {
    if (Array.isArray(item.submenus)) {
      return (
        ....
```

The result is
[Result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MENGV.png)

Any ideas?

Comment: What's your expected result?

Comment: a list of elements in the nav with the values `Dashboard `, `Profile`, `Account ` etc etc @MikhailKholodkov

Comment: i guess your JS file is required before i18next loaded the translations (async)...better would be having the keys in text and translate during your render loop.